# print a subset of data based on user input with an if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I am trying to print a subset of data based on the if statement in the code below. If I isolate the `GcoReport[Company == Entities[1], ]` code, it runs perfectly. However in the if statement it only gives me the value of `Entities[1, ]`

```
GcoReport <- read.csv("GCO report.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
inputEntity = readline(prompt = 'Enter entity')
ListOfEntities <- data.frame(UniqueEntities = unique(GcoReport$Company))
Entities <- data.frame(ACYC = GcoReport[Company == Company[1], ],
                   ARCI = ListOfEntities[2, ],
                   AIH = ListOfEntities[3, ],
                   ARE = ListOfEntities[4, ],
                   ATCI = ListOfEntities[5, ],
                   APH = ListOfEntities[6, ],
                   CYCBR = ListOfEntities[7, ],
                   COMESEC = ListOfEntities[8, ],
                   IBERINF = ListOfEntities[9, ],
                   GH = ListOfEntities[10, ])
GcoReportEntityACYC <- GcoReport[Company == Company[1], ]
if (inputEntity == "ACYC"){ GcoReport[Company == Entities[1,], ]}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here. `Entities[1,]` is a `data.frame`, and it looks like `Company` is a column in `GcoReport`? What do you expect will happen when you compare a `data.frame` with a value?

Comment: The data.frame entries contains the unique values that are in the column Company. If a user enters "ACYC" I want R to filter based on the unique value within Company that is equal to Entities[1,]